# Firing events in Twitter Bootstrap's Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Once the carousel has slid, I want to add a value to an input outside of the ID `myCarousel`.

The function to implement an event once the carousel has slid is this:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
  $('input[name=linkOnly]').val('Test')
}
```

I want to fire an event once a particular slide slides. I've tried something like `$('#myCarousel li[data-slide-to=1]').bind('slid', function() ...` but it doesn't register.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just setup an event handler on the appropriate event and then choose to do anything based on which slide is `.current`. For example, to trigger some javascript when slide 1 cycles in:

```
$(document).on("slid", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).find(".active").data("slide-to") == 1) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

From a quick test, this doesn't seem to work unless it attached to an element above the carousel (you'd also need to change things a little if you had more than one carousel).

**EDIT**: After a quick look, the reason the above doesn't work if bound to the carousel itself is that the `active` class isn't added until immediately after the `slid` event is triggered (it seems that if the handler is added to a parent element, the `active` class gets added while the `slid` event bubbles up). You can get around this by using `setTimeout` to delay the triggered behaviour (works even with a timeout of `0`):

```
$("#myCarousel").on("slid", function(event) {
  var carousel = $(event.target);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (carousel.find(".carousel-indicators .active").data("slide-to") === 1) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

Whether the extra code is worth it is up to you, although it may be a little more stable. It may even be worth putting in a small delay (instead of `0`), just to make sure that things do work the way you expect them to.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to refer to the `carousel` on 'slid' instead of the `document`? Replacing it with `carousel` or `#myCarousel` doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when I did a quick test that it doesn't work if it's attached to the carousel itself, although I'm not entirely sure why. Any higher level element should work though, so I don't know if it's an option to bind it to the carousel's parent or whatnot (I just used `document` as an example).

Comment: Worked out why it doesn't work on the element itself, updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thank you! (What is the `0` for at the end?)

Comment: `setTimeout` takes two arguments, the first being the code to execute, and the second being the delay (in milliseconds) to wait before doing do (see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)). In this case `0` seems to be enough, but it might be worth bumping it up slightly, just to be safe.